# GridView frozen header line

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

It it possible to do frozen header line in GridView ?
I'm using VS 2010, c#.

TY

Answer (score 1):

You can not frozen header row of GridView, but you can do one thing put a html table with two rows, in second row add gridView and hide the header row of it and in first row create label at run time which will looks like Grid header.